# Find the closest smaller value of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I think what I want is pretty simple but I can't really find the correct solution.

I have this kind of array in Javascript :

```
[0, 38, 136, 202, 261, 399]
```

And I get a generated value from 0 to 600 on a button click. What I need is to find the nearest lower value in this array.

For example, if the generated value is 198, I want to get 136 as the result. If the generated value is 300, I want 261... If it's 589, I want 399 etc etc.

Until now, I have tried with this code :

```
var theArray = [ 1, 3, 8, 10, 13 ];
var goal = 7;
var closest = null;

$.each(theArray, function(){
    if (closest == null || Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(closest - goal)) {
        closest = this;
    }
});

alert(closest);
```

But it only returns the closest value... Now I need the to get only the closest smaller value for the given number... How can I improve my algorithm to fit my needs?

Thanks!

Comment: Is you array always sorted?

Comment: Forgot to mention that yes, it will be always sorted in the order of the example ;-)

Comment: `&& goal - this > 0` may work

Comment: Then it will be just before the first element that is grater than your number.

Comment: What do you need the result to be if the goal is below any of the numbers in theArray ?

Comment: @John, I need it to be the first value of the array

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if I am correct or not.

Comment: what happens if the generated value is `202` which is also present in the defined array... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you array is sorted, and small enough, a really simple mode to do what you want it's simplly iterate over the array until `number > number-in-array` then return the number on the previous position.

```
function getClosestValue(myArray, myValue){
    //optional
    var i = 0;

    while(myArray[++i] < myValue);

    return myArray[--i];
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Do you need to initialize `i`?

Comment: if `i` is not defined at any point of the code, the JS will initialize it with a default value "undefined"; then, since you are treating it as a number, it will assume 0 as default value. Note that since it's a `++i` (sorry I mistaked the code, i'm fixing it), the first access will be at `myArray[1]`. You can also initialize it, if you want, there is no problem :)

Answer (score 13):

Reverse the array and use `find`

```js
let arr = [0, 38, 136, 202, 261, 399];
let val = 300;
let number = arr.reverse().find(e => e <= val);
console.log(number);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to filter the array to find the closest smaller values and then use the `Math.max()` function with the spread operator:

```js
// Array to select value
let array = [0, 38, 136, 202, 261, 399];

// Random value
let random = 168;

// Filtering array with closest smaller values [0, 38, 136]
let filtered = array.filter(num => num <= random);

// The closest value will be the maximum
let closest = Math.max(...filtered);
```

In one line of code:

```js
let closest = Math.max(...array.filter(num => num <= random));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit if the item is greater or equal to the wanted value. Otherwise assign the actual value as return value.

This proposal works for sorted arrays.

```js
function getClosest(array, value) {
    var closest;
    array.some(function (a) {
        if (a >= value) {
            return true;
        }
        closest = a;
    });
    return closest;
}

var array = [0, 38, 136, 202, 261, 399];

console.log(getClosest(array, 100)); //  38
console.log(getClosest(array, 198)); // 136
console.log(getClosest(array, 300)); // 261
console.log(getClosest(array, 589)); // 399
```

Comment: Nice! dose `some()` loops through all items of there array or not? dose it stops when condition of the function is true?

Comment: if stops if the callback returns a *truthy* value.